# Trying to glob data in brackets based on a RE match in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python to grab stanzas of data from an application log based on matched text.  A pseudo example would look something like this:

```
Error_Paragraph = [
    data1 = 'abcdefg'
    data2 = '123556'
    data3 = 'supercalifragilistic'
    data4 = 'expealadocious'
    ....
    data106 = 'critical info'
    ....
]
```

There are many stanzas in these logs... all with "data106" type identifiers.  What's the best way to grab only the stanza's that match "Error_Paragraph"?  It would be useful to grab the whole paragraph, but I'm specifically looking for only "data106" in "Error_Paragraph"

I've tried a couple iterations of this, but can't seem to suck down the paragraphs correctly.  What would be really nice would be sucking this all in to a dictionary so I could access the items as needed.

Thanks!

Example of current attempt:

```
import re
import gzip
import sys

f = gzip.open( sys.argv[1], 'rb')

dataDict = re.findall(r"Error_Paragraph = \[[^\]]*data106 = '([^']*)'", s)

print dataDict
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
File "./logfile.txt", line 10
dataDict = re.findall(f"^\$Error_Paragraph = \[[^\]]*data106 = '([^']*)'", s)
```

Comment: `findall` is documented to return a list of either groups or `tuple`s (where the `tuple`s would contain multiple groups). The output looks like it may be some kind of error. That's the exact output; there's nothing else? What is `s`? Your code uses it, but it's not defined anywhere in the code you share.

Comment: Also, can the text contain square brackets (`[]`)?

Comment: The output looks like a part of an error traceback. Please post the full traceback.

Comment: You need to actually uncompress, extract and read the file before searching it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these stanzas don't contain `[`brackets`]`, you can search for

```
Error_Paragraph = \[[^\]]*data106 = '([^']*)'
```

and then look at the match's `.groups(1)`. `re.findall()` will do that automatically for you:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """Some_Paragraph = [
...     data1 = 'abcdefg'
...     data106 = 'uninteresting info'
... ]
...
... Error_Paragraph = [
...     data3 = 'supercalifragilistic'
...     data106 = 'critical info'
... ]
...
... Other_Paragraph = [
...     data4 = 'expealadocious'
...     data106 = 'boring info'
... ]"""
>>> re.findall(r"Error_Paragraph = \[[^\]]*data106 = '([^']*)'", s)
['critical info']
```

Comment: @Tim-Pietzker - thanks for the reply.

Due to the current size of the logfiles, I'm reading them in from another file.  I've modified my attempt and pasted it in the original post... butchering your suggestion:

Comment: My solution assumes that the file contents have been read into `s`. You need to do that before you can use a regular expression, as they only work on strings, not on files.